# Finding minimal polynomial of ${e^{{2\pi}i/3}} + 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to find the minimal polynomial of this.  I tried setting ${e^{{2\pi}i/3}} + 2$ = $\alpha$ but got stuck there.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** $$\alpha = e^{2\pi i/3}+2\Longrightarrow\alpha -2=e^{2\pi i/3}\Longrightarrow (\alpha -2)^3=(e^{2\pi i/3})^3$$

Next use the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) whilst noting that you'll be dealing with a polynomial of degree $3$. If required use [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) to help you finding an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Thank you, both comments were very helpful. I didn't even think about then squaring/cubing after.

Comment: @mathmansam You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

$\alpha=2+e^{i2\pi/3}\implies \alpha-2=e^{2i\pi/3}$ and then $(\alpha-2)^2=e^{4i\pi/3}$

Since, $e^{2i\pi/3}+e^{4i\pi/3}=-1\implies (\alpha-2)^2+(\alpha-2)=-1$

This is a polynomial of degree $2$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we take ${e^{{2\pi}i/3}} + 2$ = $\alpha$ as above.  Then $(\alpha-2)^3$ = $e^{{2\pi}i}$ and famously $e^{{2\pi}i}$ = 1.

So simplifying we get $\alpha^3-6\alpha^2+12\alpha-7=0$

By Eisenstein's criterion we know this is irreducible with $p=3$ and it is easy to show that ${e^{{2\pi}i/3}} + 2$  is a root.  Thus the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$.